# Dual boot vs package installation

Tags: dual-boot, ubuntu-studio

I'm interested in Ubuntu Studio and I have Ubuntu 16.04. My Laptop has 4 GB of RAM and a 500GB hard disk.

My question is as follows. What are the disadvantages and advantages of a Dual Boot against an installation of the packages in this case, and vice versa?

The question arises from the fact that Ubuntu Studio uses a kernel with better response in the audio/graphics, etc tasks but a lower performance in general.

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.

Comment: @waltinator wish this advice had been more widely given when I first tried dual booting